# Diferencias sobre el método replace() y put()?

Tags: java, map

Tengo una duda y es que al trabajar con maps no sé la diferencia de ambos métodos , se que put es para asignar una pareja clave/valor , pero replace? Como dice el nombre será para reemplazar o la clave o valor , pero no me aclaro con ambos métodos. Espero que me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aunque `put` y `replace` son parecidas, no son exactamente iguales:

- [`put`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-): asocia el valor con la clave en el mapa.
- [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#replace-K-V-): asocia el valor con la clave en el mapa, sólo si la clave existe ya en el mapa.

La diferencia pues está en sí la clave tiene un valor asociado o no:

- Si la clave ya existe en el mapa, las dos funcionan igual (se reemplaza el valor asociado a la clave).
- Si la clave no existe en el mapa: `put` asociará el valor a esa clave, mientras que `replace` no hará nada.

Comment: +1 Pero deberías poner el linka al doc de Map, no al de HashMap. Agrego que: 1) `replace` es (tipicamente) mucho menos usada - y fue agregada en Java 8 2)  También fue agregada `putIfAbsent` , cuya diferencia con `replace` es bastante sutil

Comment: Con el índice a qué se refiere?

Comment: @leonbloy Gracias por la nota, voy a cambiar los enlaces para que apunten a Map y no a HashMap

Comment: @DioniGálvezCamacho me refiero a la clave, voy a actualizar la respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias , me sirvió bastante @AlvaroMontoro